# Running 2 threads simultaneously

Tags: java, multithreading, network-programming, simultaneous-calls

In the case of an IM client.  I have made 2 separate threads to handle sending packets (by std io) and receiving packets.  The question is how to make these 2 threads run simultaneously so that I can keep prompting for input while at the same time be ready to receive packets at any time?

I have already tried setting a timer but the data is always lost receiving.

Comment: In general a snippet of code that demonstrates your behaviour goes a long way toward getting a good quality answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you might have missed something significant with either Threads, Streams or both :-)

You can start a new thread like this:

```
myThread.start();
```

The thread will be started and the run() method will be executed automatically by the jvm.

If the threads run-method is reading from a Stream, and it is the only one reading,  it will not "miss" anything in that stream.

Answer (score 21):

Without more details, it is hard to give a complete answer.  Nevertheless, here is the code for starting two threads:

```
Thread thread1 = new Thread () {
  public void run () {
    // ... your code here
  }
};
Thread thread2 = new Thread () {
  public void run () {
    // ... your code here
  }
};
thread1.start();
thread2.start();
```

Comment: my send and receive threads rely on sending and listening on UDP socket respectively. from what i can understand, your sample codes seem to inject the thread in the code instantly. i have created a runnable class for them, so will your approach be applicable to such?

Comment: I don't know what "inject the thread in the code instantly" means.  Perhaps you can post sample code to further explain what you mean?

Comment: as in ur code is capable of creating a thread locally in a main

Comment: @lamsait: My code creates new threads which run independently.  These are created wherever you execute them.  I agree with Karlp that you seem to have a fundamental misunderstaning of threads.

Comment: yes indeed, i have to admit that in writing this IM service program 70% of the syntax, methods and classes are never heard of before.  Big thanks to both you and Karlp.

Answer (score 7):

Well, they won't run *simultaneously* unless you have a multiprocessor computer, but that's not usually the issue.  What will happen is that each thread will get a slice of time, more or less alternatively.

If you're losing I/O, it's probably not the threading that's your real problem.  can you tell us how you're reading this stuff?